# Showing admob interstitial calls onPause, same one as getting a phone call

Tags: android, admob

I am having a hard time differentiating when an ad is shown Vs when the activity is going on the background.

In my app, when the user press the home button or get a phone call, then the onPause is called and as  result I destroy the current activity and go back to the main menu. I am using Admob to display interstitial and apperently, showing an adv invokes the OnPause method which cause the above behviour.

I don't want terminate the current activity because of ad showing but any other call to the onPause (by deliberately bringing the activity to background) should terminate the current activity.

How can I fix it? Basically, how can I distinguish between the OnPause resulting from Admob versus other onPauses

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not following your use case.

Essentially you should treat both scenarios identically. The user has left the app.

You shouldn't be doing any explicit destruction of the activity during onPause. You might want to terminate or hibernate some of your artifacts, such as Threads etc.

Comment: My use case is that I want the activity to be killed if user gets a phone call or press Home.  I implemented that in the OnPause method. The problem that interstitial.show()  for admob interstitial causes the onpause to be called. I don't want to terminate my activity when I display an ad

Comment: If the user presses Home or gets a phone call your Activity will be paused and may be killed by the Android framework. You do not need to explicitly kill it, and probably shouldn't

Comment: I have a reason for doing it. I wanted it to go previous activity in that case. My question is how to know that admob interstitial is causing the the onpause so I don't revert back to to the previous one

Comment: OK, I **strongly** advise against repurposing the home button but if you set up an AdListener you will be able to tell when the Interstitial is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

What version of the AdMob SDK are you using? This solution will work with Google Play Services.

Lets say that this is how you setup your interstitial:

```
//Here is where you setup your interstitial
//...
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded(){
        adView.show();
    }
});
```

In your onPause() method you can do the following:

```
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if(adView != null) {
        adView.setAdListener(null);
    }
}
```

This works because by the time the onPause method is called because of a new interstitial, the ad will already be in the process of being shown and will display normally. However, if onPause() is called because of something else, like the Home button being pressed, it will disable new interstitials from being shown.

Only caveat is if you're using other callback methods available from the AdListener.